# Empty value on Polymer computed attribute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, polymer

I am trying to use computed attribute in Polymer but I always get an empty value. In this case I have an attribute in my custom element called datagraph. And I make a post request to a server, get a JSON file, calculate the result and then show it. This is my custom element:

```
<dom-module id="cost-card">
  <template>
    <style>
      p.datos3{
        color: #10cebc;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        margin-top: 0px;
      }
    </style>  
    <p class="datos3">{{datagraph}}</p>  
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "cost-card",

      properties:{
    usr:{
      type: Number,
      value: 2
    },
    command:{
      type: String,
      value: "SP_GetCostoCampania"
    },  
    datagraph:{
      type: Number,
      computed: 'getCost(command,usr)'
    }
  },

      getCost: function(command,usr){

        var options = {
          hostname: 'localhost',
          path: '/',
          port: 8081,
          secure: false,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'x-powered-by': 'HTTPClient.js'
          },
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        var innerCost;

        var example1 = new HTTPClient(options);
        example1.post("/executeGraph1?command="+ command + "&param1=" + usr, function (err, res, body) {

          body = JSON.parse(body);

          innerCost = body[0].price * body[0].exchengeRate;
        });

        return innerCost;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I have an express server running, information is being delivered correctly but the {{datagraph}} tag keeps empty. I think it may be because the post request is an anychronous task, and the value is being delivered later but I have also tried using Promise with the same result.

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've hinted, `getCost` is always going to return undefined because `return innerCost` is going to execute before the post's callback.

[Computed properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#computed-properties) are meant to take in other properties as arguments and are designed to be synchronous. If `getCost` took in some argument, even then you would want to use an observer that directly sets `this.datagraph` within the callback.

Since you aren't feeding any arguments into `getCost`, I would suggest you instead use a [`ready` callback](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#lifecycle-callbacks) that makes the post request and sets `this.datagraph` within the callback.

For example:

```
Polymer( {
    is: "cost-card",

    properties: {
        usr: { type: Number, value: 2 },
        command: { type: String, value: "SP_GetCostoCampania" },
        datagraph: Number
    },

    observers: [ "getCosto(command, usr)" ],

    getCosto: function ( command, usr ) {

        var options = {
            hostname: "localhost",
            path: "/",
            port: 8081,
            secure: false,
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "x-powered-by": "HTTPClient.js" },
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };

        const uri = `/executeGraph1?command=${command}&param1=${usr}`;
        new HTTPClient( options ).post( uri, ( err, res, body ) => {

            // values have changed, ignore result (ideally cancel the HTTP request)
            if ( command !== this.command || usr !== this.usr ) return;

            body = JSON.parse( body );

            this.datagraph = body[ 0 ].price * body[ 0 ].exchengeRate;

        } );

    }

} );
```

Comment: I actually feed get Cost with 2 other arguments but deleted them here to simplify the code shown. i didn't knwo it would make a differnce. I will edit the question. Could you tell me if this new info changes what you have suggested as an answer?

Comment: Sorry, I edited your code, not mine. Now it is correct

Comment: In that case, you'd want to use an observer. I've updated my code showing that.

Comment: I have made the changes and the function is actually being executed but the field is still empty

Comment: Likely due to `this` being switched to `window`. I've changed my example to use an arrow function, which should help preserve `this`. If it does not, you can use `const that = this;` before executing the HTTP request and modifying `that.datagraph`.

Comment: I applied the `const that = this` suggestion and it worked excelent. Thank you for your time and help.